# DropDownList Property to display

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have the following classes:
`User` and `Medic`, that inherits from `User`.

`User` has:
`Id`, `Name`...

`Medic` has:
`Crm` (numeric value)...

In a view, I want do display a DropdownList with Medic's `Id` for options value, and `Name` (inherited) for display...

But using `@Html.DropDownList("MedicId")` I have, for default, the `Crm` property being displayed.

Someone knows a way to set the display property to `Name`?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I have not observed, but in my Controller I have the way to do it

```
ViewBag.MedicId = new SelectList(db.Medics, "Id", "Nome");
```